# Sort each section separately using bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I use wikipedia syntax in text area. My text looks like this...

```
=main-heading=
test
again
practice
==sub-heading==
america
usa
india
```

I use the bookmarklet that I found here...

https://gist.github.com/aquilax/ac94ea6003f2ddb1e1fd6195c00ac3d9

When I sort, I get this. How do I sort each section separately?

```
==sub-heading==
=main-heading=
again
america
india
practice
test
usa
```

Expected:

```
=main-heading=
again
practice
test
==sub-heading==
america
india
usa
```

This awk command works:

> awk '/=/ {c++} {print c+1, $0}' t1.txt | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2- |
> sed '/^$/d'

But awk can not be used in browser. Is it possible to include transform in JS bookmarklet?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
function sortSections() {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

  textarea.value = textarea.value
    .trim()
    .split(/\n(?==.+=$)/m)
    .map(section => {
      const [heading, body] = section.split(/(?<==)\n/);
      return `${heading}\n${[...new Set(body.split('\n'))].sort().join('\n')}`;
    })
    .join('\n');
}
```

```html
<textarea cos="40" rows="10">=main-heading=
test
again
practice
==sub-heading==
india
america
usa
india</textarea>

<button onclick="sortSections();">Sort</button>
```

Bookmarklet:

```js
javascript: {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

  void (textarea.value = textarea.value
    .trim()
    .split(/\n(?==.+=$)/m)
    .map(section => {
      const [heading, body] = section.split(/(?<==)\n/);
      return `${heading}\n${[...new Set(body.split('\n'))].sort().join('\n')}`;
    })
    .join('\n'));
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: {  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');  void (textarea.value = textarea.value    .trim()    .split(/\n(?==.+=$)/m)    .map(section => {      const [heading, body] = section.split(/(?<==)\n/);      return `${heading}\n${[...new Set(body.split('\n'))].sort().join('\n')}`;    })    .join('\n'));}">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Comment: Yes. This is correct. But I am not able to create a bookmarklet using this code.

Comment: @shantanuo Added the bookmarklet variant.

Comment: When I copy paste the code, the bookmarklet does not work.

Comment: @shantanuo Is there any error message in the console from the bookmarklet?

Comment: There is no error. But it does not sort the text in any text-area. Is it possible to create a bookmarklet link?

Comment: @shantanuo Not sure if I understand correctly. I've added a snippet with HTML in the answer. If you press "Run code snippet" you will be able to drag the link to bookmarks.

Comment: Can I get distinct values? I guess I should add .uniq() method. But I am not sure.

Comment: @shantanuo What data structure do you need to get? Can you provide an example?

Comment: For e.g. in the sub-heading if I write "india\n  usa\n  india\n". When I sort, I need to keep only distinct names. india should appear only once.

Comment: You have to use "set" function as shown here: https://gist.github.com/aquilax/ac94ea6003f2ddb1e1fd6195c00ac3d9

Comment: @shantanuo In pure JS there is no  `.uniq()` method, but there is a workaround with `Set`. I've edited all the snippets to add deduplication.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333826/increase-the-text-area-to-view-more-lines-of-text

Comment: @shantanuo It seems you've just got another answer there)