# Bookmarklet to increase text area

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Question is very similar to (my own) question posted here...

[Increase the text area to view more lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333826/increase-the-text-area-to-view-more-lines-of-text/)

But I am looking for a way to get more space to write on this site:

paraphrasetool.com

I tried to modify the bookmarklet as mentioned below but it did not work.

```
// Find the text area.
element = document.getElementById('text_entry_entry_text_input')

// Calculate new height.
newHeight = Math.max(500, element.scrollHeight)

// Set height of element.
element.style.height = newHeight + 'px'
```

I am not sure if the textarea ID is correct.

---

Update:

There are 2 text boxes on the site and both should be enlarged so that the text can be compared side-by-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, you just need to add additional js to remove its parent's `max-height` and `height` property:

```
javascript: (() => {
    // Find the textareas.
    const element = document.getElementById('text_entry_entry_text_input')
    const element2 = document.getElementById('text_entry_text_area')

    // Calculate new height.
    const newHeight = Math.max(500, element.scrollHeight, element2.scrollHeight)

    // Set height of element.
    element.style.height = newHeight + 'px'
    element2.style.height = newHeight + 'px'

    const parentElm = document.querySelector('[data-testid="text_entry_paraphrase_text_entry"]')
    parentElm.style.maxHeight = "none"
    parentElm.style.height = "auto"
    element2.parentElement.style.maxHeight = "none"
    element2.parentElement.style.height = "auto"

    const parentChildren = document.querySelectorAll('.h-full')
    parentChildren.forEach(child => child.classList.remove('h-full'))
})();
```

Comment: Getting error "Redefinition of 'parent'"

Comment: Can you create a bookmarklet link?

Comment: @shantanuo udpated the answer

Comment: This is changing only left text box. If the right input box is not enlarged then I am not able to compare old and new text.

Comment: @shantanuo you should include that criteria in question as well imo

Comment: @shantanuo that should do the trick

Comment: awesome! appreciate your help.